# Natural deduction without premises given?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Normally when given a question like $Q \wedge P, R \vdash P \wedge R$

I can do box proof like:

$\dfrac{\dfrac{Q \wedge P^{~\text{(assumption)}}}{P}{^\text{($\wedge$-elimination)}}\quad R^{~\text{(assumption)}}}{P\wedge R}{^\text{($\wedge$ introduction)}}
\\\text{ (Q.E.D.)}$

But what about when I'm asked to prove $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$?

Do I just start with assumption as $A$?

Comment: You use the $\to$ introduction rule, which means you start with a temporary assumption of $A$ and derive $B\to A$ (also using $\to$-introduction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what about when I'm asked to prove $A→(B→A)$?
>
> Do I just use start with assumption as $A$?

Yes, assume $A$.   Next assume $B$, and lo, *somehow* derive $A$ from those assumptions.   Finally use conditional introduction a few times to *discharge* those assumptions.